A parallelepiped has a volume of $216 \text{ cm}^3$ and the total area $216 \text{ cm}^2$. Prove that the parallelepiped is a cube.
The problem
A parallelepiped has a volume of $216 \text{ cm}^3$
and the total area
$216 \text{ cm}^2$. Prove that the parallelepiped is a cube.
My question
I don't understand if we are talking about a rectangular parallelepiped or a simple one.
It seems impossible to show this if we are talking about a simple parallelepiped, because in the demonstration we also have to include that the lines are perpendicular to the parallel planes(on the bases), which I don't know how to demonstrate. If we do this, I can continue the problem.
The demonstration is we are talking about a rectangular one:
We note the sides of it with $a,b,c$
So we will have  $abc=2ab+2bc+2ac=216$
I thought of trying some inequalities to solve this with equality only if a=b=c...
I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

"I can solve the problem if it's a rectangular one.". How do you do it?

By total area, do you mean the surface area? (just clarification)

The approach that you used for the rectangular case should be easily modifiable to the simple case. Please share what you've done. The volume condition implies that $abc \geq 216$, with equality iff we're in the rectangular case. $\quad$ EG Even though a $ 2 \times 2 \times 26$ parallelepiped has a surface area of 216, the volume will be at most $ 2 \times 2 \times 26 = 104$. If it's extremely slanted so that the height tends to 0 (or the base area tends to 0, or both), then the volume tends to 0. So there is no $ 2 \times 2 \times 26$ solution even if we allow for simple ones.

@StéphaneJaouen see my edit

@CalvinLin see my edit

@IONELABUCIU I do not see how you solved the problem. I see you set it up. Can you state the inequality that you used to demonstrate $a=b=c$? (Or if you're unable to do so, let us know.)

@CalvinLin Sorry, but I realised i had a mistake in my idea, so, , no, i can't state that inequality...

What do you get when you directly apply AM-Gm to $ab+bc+ca = 216/2$?

@CalvinLin We get that $a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq 108$

Great! That's one possible conclusion. $\quad$ Can you compare $abc $ against $216$?  Can equality hold?

@CalvinLin Does $abc \geq 216$ with the equality if the parallelipiped is rectangular

@IONELABUCIU Well, I gave the example of a $2 \times 2 \times 26$ parallelepiped which  would contradict your claim that $ abc \geq 216$.  $\quad$ Yes, the goal is to show that we have equality iff rectangular and equal sides.

Let $ABCD-EFGH$ be the given parallelepiped which satisfies the followings :

The volume is $216$, and the total area is $216$

$AB\parallel DC\parallel EF\parallel HG$

$AD\parallel BC\parallel EH\parallel FG$

$AE\parallel BF\parallel CG\parallel DH$


Let $l$ be the line $EF$.
Let $\alpha$ be the plane on which $EFGH$ exists.
Let $\beta$ be the plane which is perpendicular to $\alpha$ and passes through the line segment $AD$.
First, let us transform the parallelepiped $ABCD-EFGH$ to $ABCD-E_2F_2G_2H_2$ in such a way that $ABCD$ is fixed, $E_2F_2$ is on $\ell$, $E_2F_2G_2H_2$ is on $\alpha$, $ADH_2E_2$ is on $\beta$, and $EFGH\equiv E_2F_2G_2H_2$.

Then we can see that the volume of $ABCD-E_2F_2G_2H_2$ is still $216$. Also, we have $\text{Area}(ABF_2E_2)=\text{Area}(ABFE)$ and $$\text{Area}(ADH_2E_2)\color{red}{\le}\text{Area}(ADHE)\tag1$$
(The equality of $(1)$ is attained only when the plane $ADHE$ is perpendicular to $\alpha$, i.e. when $\angle{BAE}=90^\circ$)
So, the total area $S_1$ satisfies
$$S_1=2(\text{Area}(ABCD)+\text{Area}(ABF_2E_2)+\text{Area}(ADH_2E_2))\le 2(\text{Area}(ABCD)+\text{Area}(ABFE)+\text{Area}(ADHE))=216$$
Let $\gamma$ be the plane which is perpendicular to $\alpha$ and passes through $AB$.
Then, let us transform the parallelepiped $ABCD-E_2F_2G_2H_2$ to $ABCD-E_3F_3G_3H_3$ in such a way that $ABCD$ is fixed, $E_3F_3G_3H_3$ is on $\alpha$, $ABF_3E_3$ is on $\gamma$, $AE_3$ is perpendicular to $\alpha$ and $E_2F_2G_2H_2\equiv E_3F_3G_3H_3$.

Then, we can see that the volume of $ABCD-E_3F_3G_3H_3$ is still $216$. Also, we have $\text{Area}(ADH_3E_3)=\text{Area}(ADH_2E_2)$ and $$\text{Area}(ABF_3E_3)\color{red}{\le}\text{Area}( ABF_2E_2)\tag2$$
(The equality of $(2)$ is attained only when $ABF_2E_2$ is perpendicular to $\alpha$, i.e. when $ABFE$ is perpendicular to $\alpha$, i.e. when $\angle{EAD}=90^\circ$)
So, the total area $S_2$ satisfies
$$S_2=2(\text{Area}(ABCD)+\text{Area}(ABF_3E_3)+\text{Area}(ADH_3E_3))\le 2(\text{Area}(ABCD)+\text{Area}(ABF_2E_2)+\text{Area}(ADH_2E_2))=S_1$$
Next, let $\omega$ be the plane $CDH_3G_3$. Also, let $\sigma$ be the plane which is perpendicular to $\omega$ and passes through the line segment $AE_3$.
Now, let us transform the parallelepiped $ABCD-E_3F_3G_3H_3$ to $ABC_4D_4-E_3F_3G_4H_4$ in such a way that $ABF_3E_3$ is fixed, $C_4D_4H_4G_4$ is on $\omega$, $AD_4H_4E_3$ is on $\sigma$, and $DCG_3H_3\equiv D_4C_4G_4H_4$.

We can see that the parallelepiped $ABC_4D_4-E_3F_3G_4H_4$ is a rectangular whose volume is still $216$. Also, we have $\text{Area}(ABC_4D_4)=\text{Area}(ABCD)$ and $$\text{Area}(AD_4H_4E_3)\color{red}{\le}\text{Area}(ADH_3E_3)\tag3$$
(The equality of $(3)$ is attained only when $ADH_3E_3$ is on $\sigma$, i.e. when $\angle{DAB}=90^\circ$.)
So, the total area $S_3$ satisfies
$$S_3=2(\text{Area}(ABC_4D_4)+\text{Area}(ABF_3E_3)+\text{Area}(AD_4H_4E_3))\le 2(\text{Area}(ABCD)+\text{Area}(ABF_3E_3)+\text{Area}(ADH_3E_3))=S_2$$
Finally, let $a,b,c$ be the lengths of the sides of the rectangular $ABC_4D_4-E_3F_3G_4H_4$. Then, the volume $V$ is $abc=216$, and the total area $S_3$ is given by $2(ab+bc+ca)$ which satisfies $2(ab+bc+ca)\le 216$.
By AM-GM inequality, we have
$$2(ab+bc+ca)\ge 2\times 3\times (a^2b^2c^2)^{1/3}\tag4$$
Since $216\ge 2(ab+bc+ca)$ and $2\times 3\times (a^2b^2c^2)^{1/3}=216$, the equality in $(4)$ has to hold. So, $ab=bc=ca$ implies $a=b=c$.
Also, we have to have $S_3=2(ab+bc+ca)=216$, so all the equalities in $(1)(2)(3)$ also have to hold.
Therefore, the given parallelepiped has to be a cube.

Added :

why is $A(ADH_2E_2)\le A(ADHE)$

$ADH_2E_2$ is a parallelogram, so $\text{Area}(ADH_2E_2)$ is given by $AD\times d(AD,E_2H_2)$ where $d(AD,E_2H_2)$ represents the distance between the line $AD$ and the line $E_2H_2$. Also, $ADHE$ is a parallelogram, so $\text{Area}(ADHE)$ is given by $AD\times d(AD,EH)$. Since the four points $E,H,E_2,H_2$ are on the plane $EFGH$ with $EH\parallel E_2H_2\parallel AD$, we can see that $d(AD,E_2H_2)\color{red}{\le}d(AD,EH)$ (note again that the plane $ADH_2E_2$ is perpendicular to the plane $ABCD$). So, we can say that $\text{Area}(ADH_2E_2)\le \text{Area}(ADHE)$.

Thank you so much for you answer! But may I ask why $F_2$ isn't actually $F_3$ and so on with the others? I don't really understand what you said by ,,fixing" and I think a drawing would help. Thank you again!

@IONELA BUCIU : I added some drawings.

Sorry for my questions, but why is $ABF_2E_2$ a rectangle and why is $A(ADH_2E_2)\leq A(ADHE)$

@IONELA BUCIU : Sorry, you are right that $ABF_2E_2$ is not always a rectangle. (The equality $\text{Area}(ABF_2E_2)=\text{Area}(ABFE)$ still holds.) I added some explanations about why $\text{Area}(ADH_2E_2)\le \text{Area}(ADHE)$. See Added in the answer.

If $x_1,\ldots, x_p$ are linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can recursively select $u_p,v_p,u_{p-1},v_{p-1},\ldots, u_1,v_1$ such that $$u_i,v_{i+1}\in \text{span}\{x_j:j\leqslant i\},$$ $$v_i\in \text{span}\{x_j:j<i\}^\perp,$$ and $$x_i=u_i+v_i.$$  This is just, say, Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization. We can check that for each $r=1,\ldots, p$, the volume of the parallelepiped formed by $x_1,\ldots, x_r, u_{r+1},\ldots, u_p$ has the same volume as the paralellepiped of $x_1,\ldots, x_p$, and the surface area strictly decreases iff $\|u_i\|<\|x_i\|$ iff $x_i$ is not already orthogonal to each of $x_1,\ldots, x_{i-1}$. So we end up with the parallelepiped formed by $u_1,\ldots, u_p$, all of which are orthogonal to each other, and note that the volume of this parallelepiped is the same as that of $x_1,\ldots, x_p$ and the surface area of $u_1,\ldots, u_p$ is strictly less than the surface area of $x_1,\ldots, x_p$ iff $x_1,\ldots, x_p$ are not all mutually orthogonal. So the smallest ratio of surface area to volume will occur only on right parallelepipeds.
For our example in $\mathbb{R}^3$, by rotating, we can actually assume we have $$x=(x_a,0,0),$$ $$y=(y_a,y_b,0)$$ and $$z=(z_a,z_b,z_c).$$  Consider the parallelepiped formed by $x,y,z$, then by $x,y,(0,0,z_c),$ then by $x,(0,y_b,0),(0,0,z_c),$ and note that volumes don't change and surface areas either decrease or the quantities we zeroed out were already zero.

Thank you so much for your answer, but may i ask if there is any way to solve it without vectors or functions, because i dont know to work with them? Thanks again!

What method(s) do you have for finding the volume of a parallelogram that's not a rectangle, or a parallelepiped that's not a rectangular prism?

You requested a solution w/o vectors. I'd suggest to use the formulas for volume and total suface as shown in Wikipedia. A closer look to
$$V=a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot\sqrt{1+2\cdot\cos{(\alpha)}\cdot\cos{(\beta)}\cdot\cos{(\gamma)}-\cos^2{(\alpha)}-\cos^2{(\beta)}-\cos^2{(\gamma)}}\tag{1}$$
shows, it's built by two independent functions, $V=f(a, b, c)\cdot\sqrt{g(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)}$. Thus it's possible to care for $f$ and $g$ one after the other.
First:$$f(a, b, c) = p = a\cdot b\cdot (k-a-b)\ \mathrm{with}\ k=a+b+c\tag{2}$$ ($k$ the sum of three nonparallel edges). The idea for $k$ is, with all edges $=0$ there would be no volume at all, and by eleminating $c$ I have only to look for $a$ and $b$. Now I'd like to maximise $p$, therefor I solve $a\cdot b\cdot (k-a-b)\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial{a}}=0$ for $a$, result is $$a=\displaystyle\frac{k-b}{2}\tag{2.1}$$ (BTW, the $2^{nd}$ derivative to $a$ is $-2b$ so this $a$ yields a maximum for $p$). With this result substituting $a$ in $f(a, b)$ results $$p=\frac{b(b-k)^2}{4}\tag{2.2}$$
Now set $\displaystyle p\frac{\partial}{\partial{b}}=0$ and solve for $b$ results
$$b_1=\frac{k}{3}\ \mathrm{,}\ b_2=k\tag{2.3}$$
Second derivative to $b$ is $\displaystyle\frac{3b-2k}{2}$, what results with $b=b_1$ in $\displaystyle\frac{-k}{2}$ what is $\lt 0$, thus $b_1$ yields a maximum for $p$. Now $(2, 2.1, 2.3)$ shows, $f(a, b, c)$ is maximal if $a=b=c$.
Second: I take two simplifications,
i) I regard the function under the square root as $g(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ instead of $g()=\sqrt{...}$,
ii) I set $\alpha = \beta = \gamma$ as shortcut, regarding the parallelepiped like an umbrella, when folded it contains no volume. (I did the calculations before for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ separately and got the same result as with simplification.)
$$g(\alpha)=q=1+2\cdot\cos^3{(\alpha)}-3\cdot\cos^2{(\alpha)}\tag{3}$$
Same procedure as before, $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial{\alpha}}=0$ solved for $\alpha$, that is
$$-6\left(\cos\left(\alpha\right)-1\right)\cos\left(\alpha\right)\sin\left(\alpha\right)=0\tag{3.1}$$
with results $\alpha_1=2n\pi$, $\alpha_2=(2n+1)\pi$, $\alpha_3=\displaystyle\frac{\left(4n+1\right)\pi}{2}$, and $\alpha_4=\displaystyle\frac{\left(4n-1\right)\pi}{2}$ with $n$ any integer ad libitum including $0$ and negative values. When I opt for $n=0$ the check with the $2^{nd}$ derivative show $q$ will be maximal with $$\alpha = \pi / 2\tag{3.2}$$
This two steps show, the volume is maximal for a parallelepiped with edges of same length and all touching edges orthogonal -- hence, it's a cube.
So far it was just for the distinct form of the parallelepiped. Any change of the relation of edge lenght or angles will result in a lower volume. This "confines" the formula of the surface area, with the above results there is no ha and hum and the surface area is $A=6a^2$. Note, the numerical equivalence of the volumen and the surface is no proof, it gives nothing but a good feeling. To make it watertight try some ha and hum to see if there could be chance to have a shape with numerical equivalence of $A$ and $V$ (comparing the derivatives for example).
Here the ha and hum I suggested:
Since the compare of surface and volume is a multidimensional matter of $(a, b, c, \alpha , \beta , \gamma)$ I take some cut through it so to get 2D plots showing at least some evidence (for me it's satisfactory as proof).
First I change the angles, all three the same time the same amount to simplify the complexity, also the edges are the same length. $(1)$ then is
$$V=a^3\cdot\sqrt{1+2\cdot\cos^3{(\alpha)}-3\cos^2{(\alpha)}}\tag{4}$$
To keep the volume constant any change of $\alpha$ must be "compensated" by enlarging the edges:
$$a_{mod}=\frac{a}{(1+2\cdot\cos^3{(\alpha)}-3\cos^2{(\alpha)})^{1/6}}\tag{4.1}$$
The surface then is
$$A=6\cdot a_{mod}^2\cdot\sin{(\alpha)}\tag{4.2}$$
A diagram of $A/V$ with $a_{mod}$ shows, all changes of $\alpha$ by same volume result in a larger surface.

Second: Same idea but modifying edges, $\alpha$ is fixed at $\pi/2$. Enlarging one edge must be compensated by adequate reduction of another to keep volume constant. From $(1)$
$$V= (x\cdot a)\cdot b\cdot\frac{c}{x}\tag{5}$$
and $a=b=c$ (the above found shape with the maximal volume) the corresponding surface is
$$A=2(a\cdot b+a\cdot c+b\cdot c)=\frac{2a^2(x^2+x+1)}{x}\tag{5.1}$$
The diagram of $A/V$ with $x=1/2..2$ shows, change of edges by same volume results in a larger surface.

Hence I conclude, a parallelepiped with a volume of $216\ cm^3$ and the total surface of $216\ cm^2$ must be a cube -- qed.

Let $A_1,A_2,A_3$ be the base areas of the parrellelipiped with the corresponding heights $h_1,h_2,h_3$. Then, $$V=A_1h_1=A_2h_2=A_3h_3=2A_1+2A_2+2A_3$$
gives
$$h_1h_2h_3=2h_1h_2+2h_2h_3+2h_3h_1$$
and the problem reduces to rectangular case.

thanks for your answer, but why doest it refuce to the ractangular case and how do you solve this case?

@IONELABUCIU Rectangular case is by AM-GM. I am thinking about your first question. (˶˃ ᵕ ˂˶)
